# How to synchronize two function or two Messagedialog('hello').showAsync() using Javascript in windows 8?

Tags: javascript

```
function alert(){
new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Hello").showAsync().done();
new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Remo").showAsync().done();
}
```

these popups does not execute in sequence and gives error.

Answer (score 0):

```
function alert(){
    new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Hello").showAsync().done(function(){
        new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Remo").showAsync().done();
    });
}
```